# Docker Desktop on Mac - Unable to calculate image disk size

Tags: docker, macos, installation

I installed Docker Desktop on MacOS Sonoma using brew. It worked fine for a day or so and then suddenly stopped responding - perhaps once the Resource Saver mode kicked in. I see the errors below, especially “Unable to calculate image disk size,” and then the application crashes. Tried reinstalling twice to no avail. Help!

```
$ brew install --cask docker


==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
#=#=- #     #                                                                                                                                                     
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/f67f381274bfe4df3f3f5a604ee59ebb8cf9dfad/Casks/d/docker.rb
Already downloaded: ~Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/0ff04b726daf17cb41ec2efe1ff45eb335518217288c63d886bd58c52da285f4--docker.rb
==> Downloading https://desktop.docker.com/mac/main/amd64/124339/Docker.dmg
Already downloaded: ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1e74e80bf45941608261a7be2e107ed540727538de88a0923bb8d23cdd762237--Docker.dmg
==> Installing Cask docker
==> Moving App 'Docker.app' to '/Applications/Docker.app'
==> Linking Binary 'docker' to '/usr/local/bin/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-compose' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-desktop' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-desktop'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-ecr-login' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-credential-osxkeychain' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-credential-osxkeychain'
==> Linking Binary 'docker-index' to '/usr/local/bin/docker-index'
==> Linking Binary 'hub-tool' to '/usr/local/bin/hub-tool'
==> Linking Binary 'kubectl' to '/usr/local/bin/kubectl.docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.bash-completion' to '/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.zsh-completion' to '/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_docker'
==> Linking Binary 'docker.fish-completion' to '/usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/docker.fish'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.hyperkit' to '/usr/local/bin/hyperkit'
==> Linking Binary 'com.docker.cli' to '/usr/local/bin/com.docker.cli'
  docker was successfully installed!

$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

MacOS Sonoma 14.0,
Intel processor

[image]